# Docker for Mac 10.11.6 will not start, uninstall hangs and docker menu will not open when running

Tags: macos, docker

Something has gone wrong with Docker on my mac and I'm trying to remove and re-install versions but I can't get the menu open to do a factory reset.

Every version I install either says it will not run with this version of Mac OS, or it "starts" and puts the icon in the top bar but I just get the colored wheel when I mouse over it and the menu won't open.

What can I do to manually factory reset docker?

Answer (score 2):

I'd give [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) a try.

Drop the errant app onto its open window (or you can set it to auto-launch if you throw an app in the Trash) & it will offer to clean out any associated files, allowing you to have a clean start.